# String constants in C

Tags: c, compilation, c-preprocessor, c-strings

I want to define string constants for use in multiple files in my **C** program. Right now I have them in this form:

```
file.h
#ifndef FILE_H_
#define FILE_H_

  static const char *id = "ID"

#endif
```

However, although I am using this string in multiple files, I get a compiler warning saying that this variable is not being used. If I remove the static keyword, I get an error saying that the variable has multiple definitions.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Either (a) define them as preprocessor macros `#define ID "ID"` (possibly icky), or (b) define them in one source file and declare them `extern` in the header file.

Calling them static variables in your header causes them to appear in every compilation unit, which is undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

You should not define a variable in the header file & then include it accross multiple source files.
For a non-static variable It leads to violation of the **[One definition rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)** and the linker will complain.

When you define a `static` in a header, what you get is a copy of the variable in each translation unit where you include the file. This does not sattisfy your requirement of one variable being shared accross multiple files.

There can be two approaches to solve your problem:

---

If you want to use it as constant string simply use a macro

```
#define ID "ID"
```

And make sure the macro definition is visible wherever you use it

---

If you want to use it as a vairable in multiple files simply use `extern`.

**file.h**

```
extern const char *id;
```

**file2.cpp**

```
#include"file.h"

const char *id = "ID";
```

**file3.cpp**

```
#include"file.h"

//Use the variable
```

Comment: When I declare the string extern in the .h file and assign in the .c file the way you described, I get an error saying "redefinition of "id""

Comment: @user1190650: It shouldn't if you did it in exact manner I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

GCC, at least, will not warn for a static non-pointer constant:

```
static const char id[] = "ID";
```

The problem with your version is that it creates a string literal and then "throws away" the pointer to it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a macro - any file that includes that header file will have that as a "constant" (its really just replaced during the preprocessor stage of compiling):

```
#define ID "ID"
```